# CSS - Horizontal Center DIV and position sublings left and right relativ to centered DIV whayever its content

Tags: html, css

Goal is to create a dynamic Header based on user input.
Centered div is supposed to display the name of the user selection.
Right div(s) is to display information about that selection.
Left div(s) as well.

We could think about something like a City name, with at the right, its Region name, then its Country name, and at the left, inhabitant numbers, and a flag.

Each element can have a different width depending on the user input.

[image]

So i've done research, and i'm not quite sure if it's doable or not.
It seems that a table layout would be the best solution.

What do you think guys ?

Comment: This post is not answering mine.
I've just tested it, the div supposed to stay centered is not staying centered.

Comment: Or maybe i need to wrap my X sub left divs and right divs, into item right and item left. :D

I was testing with 1 div left et 2 right.